# Validation Error - The field MaxResultCount must be between 1 and 2147483647

Tags: angular, aspnetboilerplate

I've recently added a new entity to this project, however, I've come across this validation error when I click on the newly created page

[image]

I'm not so sure what's causing this issue as the other entities have nearly the same dimensions. I've searched this issue extensively online but found no suitable solution unfortunately.

Here is some of the code in the service-proxy:

```
/**
     * @param keyword (optional) 
     * @param isActive (optional) 
     * @param skipCount (optional) 
     * @param maxResultCount (optional) 
     * @return Success
     */
    getAll(keyword: string | undefined, maxResultCount: number | undefined, skipCount: number | undefined): Observable<DeductionsAndExpenseFlatDtoPagedResultDto> {
        let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/services/app/DeductionsAndExpensesFlat/GetAll?";
        if (keyword === null)
            throw new Error("The parameter 'keyword' cannot be null.");
        else if (keyword !== undefined)
            url_ += "Keyword=" + encodeURIComponent("" + keyword) + "&";
        if (maxResultCount === null)
            throw new Error("The parameter 'maxResultCount' cannot be null.");
        else if (maxResultCount !== undefined)
            url_ += "MaxResultCount=" + encodeURIComponent("" + maxResultCount) + "&";
        if (skipCount === null)
            throw new Error("The parameter 'skipCount' cannot be null.");
        else if (skipCount !== undefined)
            url_ += "SkipCount=" + encodeURIComponent("" + skipCount) + "&";
        url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");


        let options_ : any = {
            observe: "response",
            responseType: "blob",           
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                "Accept": "text/plain"
            })
        };

        return this.http.request("get", url_, options_).pipe(_observableMergeMap((response_ : any) => {
            return this.processGetAll(response_);
        })).pipe(_observableCatch((response_: any) => {
            if (response_ instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
                try {
                    return this.processGetAll(<any>response_);
                } catch (e) {
                    return <Observable<DeductionsAndExpenseFlatDtoPagedResultDto>><any>_observableThrow(e);
                }
            } else
                return <Observable<DeductionsAndExpenseFlatDtoPagedResultDto>><any>_observableThrow(response_);
        }));
    }

    protected processGetAll(response: HttpResponseBase): Observable<DeductionsAndExpenseFlatDtoPagedResultDto> {
        const status = response.status;
        const responseBlob = 
            response instanceof HttpResponse ? response.body : 
            (<any>response).error instanceof Blob ? (<any>response).error : undefined;

        let _headers: any = {}; if (response.headers) { for (let key of response.headers.keys()) { _headers[key] = response.headers.get(key); }};
        if (status === 200) {
            return blobToText(responseBlob).pipe(_observableMergeMap(_responseText => {
            let result200: any = null;
            let resultData200 = _responseText === "" ? null : JSON.parse(_responseText, this.jsonParseReviver);
            result200 = DeductionsAndExpenseFlatDtoPagedResultDto.fromJS(resultData200);
            return _observableOf(result200);
            }));
        } else if (status !== 200 && status !== 204) {
            return blobToText(responseBlob).pipe(_observableMergeMap(_responseText => {
            return throwException("An unexpected server error occurred.", status, _responseText, _headers);
            }));
        }
        return _observableOf<DeductionsAndExpenseFlatDtoPagedResultDto>(<any>null);
    }
```

And here is the typescript code:

```
import { Component, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { appModuleAnimation } from '@shared/animations/routerTransition';
import {
    PagedListingComponentBase,
    PagedRequestDto
} from 'shared/paged-listing-component-base';
import {
    DeductionsAndExpensesFlatServiceProxy,
    DeductionsAndExpenseFlatDto,
    DeductionsAndExpenseFlatDtoPagedResultDto
} from '@shared/service-proxies/service-proxies';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { NavigationRoutes, NavigationDirection, NavigationPropertyEnum, NavigationSource } from 'enums/app.enums';
import { AppUrlService } from '@shared/nav/app-url.service';
import { UserGroupService } from '@app/services/user-group.service';
import { CreateDeductionsAndExpenseFlatDialogComponent } from './create-deductions-and-expense-flat/create-deductions-and-expense-flat.component';
import { EditFlatDeductionsAndExpenseComponent } from './edit-flat-deductions-and-expense/edit-flat-deductions-and-expense.component';

class PagedDeductionsAndExpensesFlatRequestDto extends PagedRequestDto {
  keyword: string;
  isActive: boolean | null;
}


@Component({
  templateUrl: './deductions-and-expenses-flat.component.html',
  animations: [appModuleAnimation()],
    styles: [
        `
          mat-form-field {
            padding: 10px;
          }
        `
    ]
})
export class DeductionsAndExpensesFlatComponent extends PagedListingComponentBase<DeductionsAndExpenseFlatDto> {
  deductionsAndExpensesFlat: DeductionsAndExpenseFlatDto[] = [];
  keyword = '';
  isActive: boolean | null;
  passedID: number; canAdd: boolean;
  searchText: number;

  constructor(
      injector: Injector,
      private _deductionsAndExpenseFlatService: DeductionsAndExpensesFlatServiceProxy,
      private _dialog: MatDialog,
      private router: Router,
      private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
      private appUrlService: AppUrlService,
      private userGroupService: UserGroupService,
  ) {
      super(injector);
      this.appUrlService.getNavigationExtras();
  }

  getGroupName(group: number): string {
      return this.userGroupService.getGroupName(group);
  }

  list(
      request: PagedDeductionsAndExpensesFlatRequestDto,
      pageNumber: number,
      finishedCallback: Function
  ): void {

      request.keyword = this.keyword;
      request.isActive = this.isActive;

      this._deductionsAndExpenseFlatService
          .getAll(request.keyword, request.skipCount, request.maxResultCount)
          .pipe(
              finalize(() => {
                  finishedCallback();
              })
          )
          .subscribe((result: DeductionsAndExpenseFlatDtoPagedResultDto) => {

              this.deductionsAndExpensesFlat = this.appUrlService.passedId === 0 ?
                  result.items : result.items.filter(x => Array.isArray(this.appUrlService.passedId) ?
                      this.appUrlService.passedId.includes(x.aoCaseId)
                      : x.aoCaseId === this.appUrlService.passedId);
              this.canAdd = !Array.isArray(this.appUrlService.passedId) && this.appUrlService.passedId !== 0;
              this.showPaging(result, pageNumber);
          });
  }

  getSource() {
      return NavigationSource.Other;
  }

  delete(deductionsAndExpenseFlat: DeductionsAndExpenseFlatDto): void {
      abp.message.confirm(
          this.l('DeductionsAndExpenseFlatDeleteWarningMessage', deductionsAndExpenseFlat.said),
          undefined,
          (result: boolean) => {
              if (result) {
                  this._deductionsAndExpenseFlatService
                      .delete(deductionsAndExpenseFlat.id)
                      .pipe(
                          finalize(() => {
                              abp.notify.success(this.l('SuccessfullyDeleted'));
                              this.refresh();
                          })
                      )
                      .subscribe(() => { });
              }
          }
      );
  }

  createDeductionsAndExpenseFlat(): void {
      this.showCreateOrEditDeductionsAndExpenseFlatDialog();
  }

  editDeductionsAndExpense(deductionsAndExpenseFlat: DeductionsAndExpenseFlatDto): void {
      this.showCreateOrEditDeductionsAndExpenseFlatDialog(deductionsAndExpenseFlat.id);
  }

  showCreateOrEditDeductionsAndExpenseFlatDialog(id?: number): void {
      let createOrEditDeductionsAndExpenseDialog;
      if (id === undefined || id <= 0) {
          createOrEditDeductionsAndExpenseDialog = this._dialog.open(CreateDeductionsAndExpenseFlatDialogComponent, {
              data: { id: this.appUrlService.passedId, groupId: this.appUrlService.groupId }
          });
      } else {
          createOrEditDeductionsAndExpenseDialog = this._dialog.open(EditFlatDeductionsAndExpenseComponent, {
              data: id
          });
      }

      createOrEditDeductionsAndExpenseDialog.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
          if (result) {
              this.refresh();
          }
      });
  }

  getNavigationPropertyEnum() {
      return NavigationPropertyEnum.DetailedDeductionsAndExpenses;
  }
}
```

Finally, here is the log output.
[image]

Any assistance is greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I've solved the issue. I switched over my parameters which resulted in different values being passed through.

```
this._deductionsAndExpenseFlatService
          .getAll(request.keyword, request.skipCount, request.maxResultCount)
          .pipe(
              finalize(() => {
                  finishedCallback();
              })
          )
```

Didn't match with

```
getAll(keyword: string | undefined, maxResultCount: number | undefined, skipCount: number | undefined)
```

so I swapped the parameters around here:

```
this._deductionsAndExpenseFlatService
          .getAll(request.keyword, request.maxResultCount, request.skipCount)
          .pipe(
              finalize(() => {
                  finishedCallback();
              })
          )
```

Which solved the issue. Closing this query.